# Date range query in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, range

I am trying to run the following query. I know the syntax is wrong, but I can't quite figure out what is wrong with it. Basically, I am trying to find how many games have dates that are within 45 days of today. I have a model called Game that has a field attribute called date_of_game. My query:

```
Game.where(date_of_game: <= (Time.now + 45.days)).count
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You said:

> how many games have dates that are within 45 days of today

But your code will retrieve all the games having a date less than Today + 45 days, which means it would return Game of last year, for example. To follow your statement, you should use:

```
Game.where(date_of_game: Date.current..(Date.current + 45.days))
```

This code will return all games coming out in the next 45 days.

---

What is `..` ?

It is the operator to create Ranges. Try in your console:

```
> (1..5).each do |some_number|
>   puts some_number
> end
1
2
3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 => 1..5
```

It also works with dates:

```
> (Date.today..(Date.today+5.days)).each do |some_date|
>   puts some_date                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
> end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
2014-06-04
2014-06-05
2014-06-06
2014-06-07
2014-06-08
2014-06-09
 => Wed, 04 Jun 2014..Mon, 09 Jun 2014
```

Comment: perfect! thanks! question though - what does ".." mean? thanks!

Comment: @user1547174 It is a range operator: `1..5` will generate a range between 1 to 5. It also works with Dates. The following `Date.current..(Date.current + 45.days)` creates a Range from today to 45 days in the future. Passing it to the ActiveRecord where clause tells Rails to translate this Range into the proper SQL query, in your case: `WHERE date_of_game BETWEEN '2014-06-04' AND '2014-07-19'`

Answer (score 5):

You can't use a hash like that, use a string instead

```
Game.where("date_of_game <= ? ", (Time.now + 45.days)).count
```